# Does anyone have an x86 EGA draw pixel routine?

Tags: ms-dos, graphics, assembly, bios, x86

So far, I have gotten by with using the BIOS draw-pixel routine here: http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_10-c.html

This works of course, but I can't imagine that commercial games used this BIOS call as its pretty slow.  Considering too that 320x200 = 64K, drawing a full screen requires speed.

Writing to graphics memory is fairly straight forward for CGA, but EGA uses planar addressing and is a bit tricky to find documentation on.  I'm trying to "write games" not reinvent the wheel here.  Ideally, I'm looking for a general purpose pixel drawing routine that I can learn from and possibly just use.  Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Any pixel drawing routine will be slow. It's not intuitive, but drawing single pixels is not the fundamental operation that all other operations are based that you might think it is. A more important operation, especially for games would be bit blit or bitmap copy.

Comment: In the DOS days there were specific programming books for this. Try to get hold of them. A quick Google for *book "programming ega graphics"* turns up [this PDF](http://archive.pcjs.org/pubs/pc/magazines/pcmag/PCMAG-1986-08/PCMAG-1986-08-Exploring_The_EGA.pdf), *book "programming vga graphics"* gives many more hits, and [John's answer](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/8790/8725) suggests other search terms. Too bad I threw my books away years ago ;-)

Comment: If you're trying to write games, you really want the "PC Game Programmer's Encyclopedia", an excellent collection of text files on how to do everything in the DOS era.

Comment: If you do choose to do some single pixel after all, there's some code for 640x480 16 color VGA mode, which operates the same way, in one of my old demo projects: https://github.com/BrianKnoblauch/Circ-VGA/blob/master/CIRC.ASM

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch: IIRC, the main write mode I used on the VGA was one which didn't exist on the EGA.  On the EGA, it was necessary to set an 8-bit mask register for each pixel to be written, but on the VGA the 8-bit mask could be taken from the value written.  I think your code looks like it might be using that technique.

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch: Looking at the EGA, it smells of a "design by committee" project, since it includes logic to rotate values that were being written by 0-7 bits, but doesn't include enough coherent features to make that ability useful.  If it had included a mode where reads would always read zero, writes would be latched in an extra 8-bit register, and the rotate facility would combine the present and previous bytes written, those could have together been amazingly useful.

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch: Or, better yet, instead of using read/modify/write latches, the board could have used 32 256x1 DRAM chips and gated the write-enable signals using the written data, thus allowing pixel colors to be set directly in selected pixels without having to perform read/modify/write sequences.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Writing single pixels is a non-starter if you want any performance, even if you don't go through the overhead of a BIOS call for each pixel.

Graphics libraries in and around the EGA era were based on drawing entire lines at a time, curved lines that were segments of axis-parallel elipses, and things like filled rectangles and circles.

The interior of the big flat fills could be sped up by manipulating the write mask register: by setting more than one bit, more than one of the bit planes would accept writes at the same time, so to write a single word of FFFF or 0000 you could set or clear the bits of 16 pixels in any combination of planes you wanted. You'd first write all the planes you want to set to 0 all at once, then all the planes you want to set to 1 (or, of course, vice versa). At the boundaries of your shape, where you need to partially keep the screen content within a word or byte, you'd need to switch to a slower plane-by-plane implementation.

If you wanted more intricate graphics than you could make with plain lines or fills, you would blit (in software) bitmaps to the screen from a pre-rendered in-memory representation that was already split into planes and bytes the right way. If you wanted smooth horizontal movement, you would have 8 rendered versions of each bitmap depending on the horizontal position of the image relative to the byte boundaries.

Draw single pixels only as an absolute last resort.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense.  I have developed my own RLE routine to import bitmaps drawn in a paint tool and it works.  i was hoping to base my maps on 16x16 tiles and draw them as you move.  The benefit i guess i have with RLE is i can focus on long runs as horizontal lines.  i have not read much on blitting but this points me in the right direction!

Answer (score 4):

Source for the GEM video drivers [is available](https://github.com/sam-falvo/gem3/tree/master/MRS/GEM3X/SCREENDR/DISK2OF3/COMMON) - the files EGAMMRE1.A86 and EGAMMRE2.A86 contain functions to draw a filled rectangle (RECTFIL), an arbitrary line (ABLINE) and a 16x16 mouse pointer (MDRAW) on EGA/VGA hardware.

If you can find a copy of Richard Wilton's *[Programmer's Guide To PC Video Systems](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Programmers-Systems-Microsoft-programming-classic/dp/1556156413)*, that contains a thorough explanation of how the EGA works and provides a number of drawing functions for it.